# How to draw chart with postgresql and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, chart.js2

Can we draw a different types of charts using a data from postgresql and using node.js.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of answers you expect, but here is mine: yes.

Comment: Here's mine: 42